# How to create an email, from a template, for each element of a list in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to convert a list of email addresses into hyperlinks that when clicked will auto-populate an email template. The template uses the hyperlinked email address as the mailto target as well as adds calls to CC a secondary email specific to the primary and that has its own data set in the same worksheet.

The list goes like this:

Email1    CC1

Email2    CC2

Email3    CC3

Email4    CC4

Email5    CC5

etc....

I managed to do this for one email, if I specifically call that email in the macro.

I am trying to call the whole list respective to their assigned CC emails.

```vb
Sub Email1()
    Dim applOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim miOL As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim recptOL As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set applOL =NewOutlook.Application
    Set miOL =applOL.CreateItemFromTemplate("G:\User\Emails\EmailTemp.oft")
    Set recptOL =miOL.Recipients.Add("email1@gmail.com")
    recptOL.Type = olTo
    Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add("copy1@gmail.com")
    recptOL.Type = olCC
    miOL.Display
    Set applOL = Nothing
    Set miOL = Nothing
    Set recptOL = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Call Sheet1.Email1
    End If
End Sub
```

With this I am able to hyperlink and click Email 1 and open a template in Outlook that has a body setup and auto populates Email 1 in "To:" and Copy 1 in "CC:".

I would like to know how to do this for a list of almost 2000 entries.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a string parameter to the `Email1` sub so it could indicate the email address to add to the `CC` or `TO` field.

```
Sub Email1(emailAddress as string)
```

Then in the code you could make it configurable:

```
Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add(emailAddress)
recptOL.Type = olCC
```

In Excel you could detect the target and pass appropriate email address to the sub.

Comment: That's fine and all, but how do I do this for 2000 different entries, wouldn't this still only be used to populate the email with a single entry? I'm trying to make this an automatic process that once I click on a hyperlinked address, it will display an email template and populate the recipients that correspond to the email I clicked and all I would have to do was attach the file I need to and hit send.

Comment: You can pass the cell content (an email address) as a parameter to the method which can add the specified email address to the list of recipients.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Email1()

    Dim applOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim miOL As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim recptOL As Outlook.Recipient
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set applOL = New Outlook.Application
    Set miOL = applOL.CreateItemFromTemplate("G:\User\Emails\EmailTemp.oft")
    
    Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add(Selection.Value)
    recptOL.Type = olTo
    
    ' CC addresses one column to the right of the To addresses
    Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add(Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value)
    recptOL.Type = olCC
    
    miOL.Display
    
    Set applOL = Nothing
    Set miOL = Nothing
    Set recptOL = Nothing
    
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ' To addresses in Column A, for example
    If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
        Email1
    End If
End Sub
```